# Issue passing a string from Swift to objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, interop

This is the declaration of username in MyObjCClass.h :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSString* username;
```

This is how I affect it in MyViewController.swift :

```
// MyObjCObject.username = NSString(string: "homerSimpson") // not accepted by xCode : 'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert ?
MyObjCObject.username = "homerSimpson"
```

This is how I use the attribute in MyObjCClass.m :

```
NSLog(_username) // running error happens here
```

The error :

```
ECX_BAD_ACCESS : (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Comment: Why not (nonatomic, strong)?

Comment: You could probably duplicate this without even going through Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `assign` for pointers to objects.  You need to change `assign` to either `strong` or `weak` (or omit it completely, which I believe defaults it to `strong`), depending on what sort of memory management you want for the object.

Also, that's not how you want to use `NSLog`.  You need to use it more like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _username);
```